# Why does my Ubuntu 16.04 server pick the wrong mysql database when trying to load two different sites?

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, mysql

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server that I am hosting two websites on.

However I keep getting an `Internal server error` most of the times that I try to access the sites.

Each time I access the error file (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`) I can see that the mysql database is trying to access the correct table for the desired site. However it is using the wrong database.

For example this is my latest error;

```
[Mon Jun 19 14:37:22.765613 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1683] [client 91.143.79.131:50212] pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'validation_server.articles' doesn't exist"), referer: http://tracker.txfmedia.com/
[Mon Jun 19 14:37:22.765630 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1683] [client 91.143.79.131:50212] , referer: http://tracker.txfmedia.com/
```

It can be seen that is says `'validation_server.articles' doesn't exist` instead it should be trying to access `'stories.articles'`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The problem must be in the site's application. Which is it exactly? What installation manual did you used, etc ..?

Comment: @pa4080 It's a flask app, both of the sites are. I used the flask documentation regarding wsgi.